# Erro in create aws_codebuild_project

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codebuild

When creating the resource aws_codebuild_project I got the following error

**Error creating CodeBuild project: InvalidInputException:**

But when twice terraform apply, the codebuil is create

The code part is inside the module that creates the pipiline.
In this example the source is pipiline, and the source of pipiline is github

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "backend_code_build_policy" {
  name   = var.policy_build_backend
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.backend_data_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "codebuild-attach" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.backend_build_role.id
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.backend_code_build_policy.arn
}

resource "aws_codebuild_project" "build_iaas" {
  name = var.cb_project_backend_name
  #description   = "test_codebuild_project"
  build_timeout = "5"
  service_role  = aws_iam_role.backend_build_role.arn

  artifacts {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  source {
    type            = "GITHUB"
    location        = var.source_cb_locat_backend
    git_clone_depth = 1
  }

  #source {
  #  type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  #}

  #  cache {
  #    type     = "S3"
  #    location = "${aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket}"
  #  }

  environment {
    compute_type = var.cb_env_compute_type_backend
    image        = var.cb_env_image_backend
    type         = var.cb_env_type_backend
  }

  logs_config {
    cloudwatch_logs {
      #status      = var.cb_cloudwatch_logs_enabled_backend ? "ENABLE" : "DISABLED"
      group_name  = var.cb_cloudwatch_group_name_backend
      stream_name = var.cb_cloudwatch_stream_name_backend
    }
  }

  #vpc_config {
  #  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
  #
  #  subnets = var.vpc_zone_identifier
  #
  #  security_group_ids = [
  #    "${aws_security_group.example1.id}",
  #    "${aws_security_group.example2.id}",
  #  ]
  #}

  #tags = {
  #  Environment = "Test"
  #}
}
```

Would anyone know why the error was?